# How to align labels in different prototype cells in a custom cell view with constraints

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a custom cell view for a table. And i have 2 prototype cells. One for header and one for data. I have 3 labels in enach prototype cells. I can not align the label in header prototype cell with the label in data prototype cell with constraints.

Thanks.

### Header prototype

### Label1 --------- Label2 ----------- Label3-

Label1 ----------Label2 ------------Label3-
Cell prototype

Comment: you can not? i highly doubt that! what have you tried, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i.e. align left Label2 on prototype cell 1 with Label2 on prototype cell 2.

Comment: I want to align the marked 2 labels by ctrl dragging on storyboard. One of them is in custom cell header, and the other is in custom cell.

Comment: Please see the image, 8bitiz.com/1.png

Answer (score 0):

I think You can achieve this using storyboards just add dynamic prototype in tableview and then add ur labels and give constraints. I think this is what you want..

Comment: Please see the image using storyboards to try to align two labels in different custom cells. One for header the other for table data. http://8bitiz.com/1.png

Comment: If you want to align your cells according to your headers then just copy the labels in your header and paste it in your cell they would be on the exact same alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this only in one case read below logic.

1. Give leading space for label1 with contentView and set textAlignment to left.
2. label2 align center to contentView and set its textAlignment to centre.
3. Set leading and trailing for label2 with left right neighbors.
4. Give trailing space for label3 with contentView and set its textAlignment to right.

Here you go.

**OR**

You have to fix the width for central label(label2).